# How to remove the string double quotes when exporting array variables?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a PHP script that reads a database in TXT format, sanitize the date fields and transform it in a CSV.

I have to read a line, separate each field (which is divided by number of characters) into an array, apply the sanitize date function and export it into the CSV file in an specific order.

Take this line for example:

```
001001010006700603927229/05/201529/05/2016TELESALUD                                         J312324366523/01/2016RODRIGUEZ ALBERTO                                 0012345678                    RODRIGUEZ JUAN                                    008765432101/01/1960MTITULAR                                                                                   APLICA
```

I separate it in an array:

```
$input = [
        trim(substr($line, 0, 3)),
        trim(substr($line, 3, 3)),
        trim(substr($line, 6, 7)),
        trim(substr($line, 13, 9)),
        trim(substr($line, 22, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 32, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 42, 50)),
        trim(substr($line, 92, 1)),
        trim(substr($line, 93, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 103, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 113, 50)),
        trim(substr($line, 163, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 173, 20)),
        trim(substr($line, 193, 50)),
        trim(substr($line, 243, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 253, 10)),
        trim(substr($line, 263, 1)),
        trim(substr($line, 264, 40)),
        trim(substr($line, 304, 50)),
        trim(substr($line, 354, 10))
    ];
```

Then, after applying the function to the correspondent fields, I reorganize them with this array:

```
$output = [
    '3',
    '3',
    $input[10],
    $input[13],
    $input[15],
    $input[16],
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    $input[17],
    '',
    $input[3],
    $input[14],
    $input[4] ." " .$input[5],
    '',
    $input[19],
    $input[0] .$input[1] .$input[2] .$input[3]
];
```

Finally, with this function I export the result to the CSV:

```
fputcsv($csv, $output, ";");
```

Here come my trouble. PHP decides to include double quotes to specific fields. This is the result:

```
3;3;"RODRIGUEZ ALBERTO";"RODRIGUEZ JUAN";19600101;M;;;;;TITULAR;;006039272;0087654321;"20150529 20160529";;APLICA;0010010100067006039272
```

All the fields are supposed to be in string format, but my guess is that PHP includes the double quotes in the fields that contain a white space on them.

If I specify the enclosure as an empty character like this:

```
fputcsv($csv, $output, ";", "");
```

Or like this:

```
fputcsv($csv, $output, ';', chr(0));
```

It just doesn't write any lines in the CSV. And the apache log says that the enclosure must be a character. And a white space is not an option for us.

This script runs on a small server, but processes millions of lines. I don't want to include another function that removes the quotes.

Is there any way to tell PHP not to include those double quotes in the CSV?

Comment: The function that removes the quotes is [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Use it and stop worrying about PHP producing valid and portable CSV.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but the CSV goes to another company that explicitly says that double quotations are an illegal character for them. And if I use another function to remove the quotes it adds like 6 hours to the process. I hope there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use a different PHP function then, like fwrite()?

Comment: This actually works:

foreach ($output as $field) {
  fwrite($csv, "$field" .";");
 }
 fwrite($csv, "\n");

Not with the same performance, but it does the job. Thanks!